# Http request with UTF-8 error?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

I have to send this request using UTF-8 but it doesnt work.

How to send this request using UTF-8 formatted ?

```
 var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
       if (request.readyState == 4)
        {
            // ret
        }
    }

    httpUrl="/ISV/AddCustomerWebSite/Default.aspx?";
    httpUrl = httpUrl + "vendorID="+paramsList[0]+
                "&title="+paramsList[1]+
                "&planTypeID=" +paramsList[2];

    request.open("GET", httpUrl);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Charset=utf-8");
    request.send(null);
```

Comment: You need to encode your parameter values with `encodeURIComponent()` before adding them to the URL.

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: encodeURIComponent() is saved me thx

Comment: So @Pointy post it as a answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer form of my comment: the error probably has something to do with the parameter values not being URL-encoded:

```
 httpUrl = httpUrl + "vendorID=" +
   encodeURIComponent(paramsList[0]) +
   "&title=" +
   encodeURIComponent(paramsList[1]) +
   "&planTypeID=" +
   encodeURIComponent(paramsList[2]);
```

That encoding will (almost certainly) be un-done transparently by your server-side framework.